# X++ QueryBuilder Nested Results

Tags: axapta, query-builder, x++

I have a query that uses the Sales Table and the Sales Line table as the datasources for the query (thanks to everyone who helped with that!). In the Query Run section, how do I loop around the results for the sales lines if the sales order has more than one sales line attached to it?

```
static void TestQuery(Args _args)

{

    SalesTable salesTable;
    SalesLine salesLine;
    QueryBuildRange      querybuildrange;
    utcDateTime          mutcDateTime;
    date                 mDate;

    QueryRun queryrun = new QueryRun(new Query());
    QueryBuildDataSource datasourceA = queryrun.query().addDataSource(tableNum(SalesTable));
    QueryBuildDataSource datasourceB = datasourceA.addDataSource(tableNum(SalesLine));

    mDate        = str2Date("25/09/2016", 123);
    mutcDateTime = DateTimeUtil::newDateTime(mDate,0);
    querybuildrange = datasourceA.addRange(FieldNum(SalesTable, CreatedDateTime));
    querybuildrange.value(strFmt('>%1', mutcDateTime));

    datasourceB.relations(true);  // Link on SalesId
    datasourceB.joinMode(JoinMode::ExistsJoin);

    info(datasourceA.toString());      // This is the full query

    while (queryrun.next())
    {
        salesTable = queryrun.get(tableNum(SalesTable));
        salesLine = queryrun.get(tableNum(SalesLine));
        info(salesTable.SalesId);
        info(salesline.Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `ExistsJoins` when you need to use `InnerJoin`.

Change this line

> `datasourceB.joinMode(JoinMode::ExistsJoin);`

to

> `datasourceB.joinMode(JoinMode::InnerJoin);`

Also, you can use the `queryRun.changed(...)` method to check when a record has changed.  Like this:

```
while (queryrun.next())
{
    if (queryrun.changed(tableNum(SalesTable)))
    {
        salesTable = queryrun.get(tableNum(SalesTable));
    }

    salesLine = queryrun.get(tableNum(SalesLine));
    info(salesTable.SalesId);
    info(salesline.Name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex for your answer, I appreciate the help!